# how to display recorded audio in android app on the same layout/view

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android app development. I have started learning how to record audio in android. The problem is I want the recorded audio files to be displayed above the record button as a list and I am not sure how that exactly works. Help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please add whatever code you have tried do far in order for the community to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the layout in two parts one can contain you record button and on other you can use list view and populate your songs in that.
Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) link.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do it within your answer? Your answer borders hard on the frowned-upon "link only" answer type.

Comment: Actually this answer helped me in some way I like to code it myself rather than getting a code from the community it actually helps me learn better thanks for letting me know thathat list view is used

Comment: And if I do get it working I'll surely add the code to this page I'm working on it ryt now if I finish it I will make sure the code I used is added along with a clear explanation

Comment: @VarunKNair please mark this as answered if this helped you out